# Android - Proguard error with static String

Tags: android, static, proguard

I'm running ProGuard for my release build and trying to optimize it as much as possible. The only custom rules I've added so far are Serialization and Facebook ones. I'm running my release build now and I'm getting a stack trace and what it maps back to is really throwing me off. Here's my stack trace:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException

E/AndroidRuntime(10842):    at com.myapp.android.myapp.dh.a(Unknown Source)

E/AndroidRuntime(10842):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.b(Unknown Source)

E/AndroidRuntime(10842):    at android.support.v4.app.w.a(Unknown Source)

E/AndroidRuntime(10842):    at android.support.v4.app.p.onCreatePanelMenu(Unknown Source)

E/AndroidRuntime(10842):    at android.support.v7.a.g.a(Unknown Source)

E/AndroidRuntime(10842):    at android.support.v7.a.m.a(Unknown Source)

E/AndroidRuntime(10842):    at android.support.v7.a.g.onCreatePanelMenu(Unknown Source)
```

In mapping, com.myapp.android.myapp.dh.a is:

```
com.myapp.android.myapp.LocalFragment -> com.myapp.android.myapp.dh:
java.lang.String USER_ACCOUNT -> a
```

In my actual code it's this:

```
public static String USER_ACCOUNT = "com.myapp.android.myapp.LocalFragment.user_account";
```

Now this constant is used in multiple places throughout this Fragment, but it should never be null. Anyone seen a problem like this before? Does Proguard do weird stuff with statics?

Edit: This error is thrown and the app crashes basically as soon as I take the action that would load this Fragment.

**EDIT AGAIN**
After a bit more investigation, I was wrong about what a was. a was that Static member, but a is also a method. It's the onCreate method. I'm also seeing this error in logcat before the NPE is thrown in onCreate:

```
W/SupportMenuInflater(10842): Cannot instantiate class: android.support.v7.widget.SearchView

W/SupportMenuInflater(10842): java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context]

W/SupportMenuInflater(10842):   at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)

W/SupportMenuInflater(10842):   at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:446)

W/SupportMenuInflater(10842):   at android.support.v7.internal.view.e.a(Unknown Source)

W/SupportMenuInflater(10842):   at android.support.v7.internal.view.e.a(Unknown Source)

W/SupportMenuInflater(10842):   at android.support.v7.internal.view.c.a(Unknown Source)

W/SupportMenuInflater(10842):   at android.support.v7.internal.view.c.inflate(Unknown Source)

W/SupportMenuInflater(10842):   at com.myapp.android.myapp.dh.a(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a problem with proguard obfuscating the support libraries, or specifically, the SearchView component that you probably try to initiate in your fragment. To avoid this, you need to add few exclusions to proguard configuration file (proguard.cfg).

```
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }
```

This will keep all classes and interfaces inside the widget package of the support library from being obfuscated.